# Bad performance for NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am trying to load items from `CoreData` into a `UITableView`. The initial way I did it was to simply grab all the objects from my `BankInfo` entity, stuff them into an array, and then use the array to populate the `UITableViewCells`:

```
- (NSMutableArray *) bankInfos
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"BankInfo" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    NSError *error;
    NSMutableArray *bankInfos = (NSMutableArray*)[context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    return bankInfos;
}
```

I'd heard that `NSFetchedResultsController` could improve performance / memory management so I tried it out (basically implemented it the way [Ray Wenderlich tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/999/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-use-nsfetchedresultscontroller) recommended):

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {

    if (_fetchedResultsController != nil) {
        return _fetchedResultsController;
    }

    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
        entityForName:@"FailedBankInfo" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    NSSortDescriptor *sort = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]
        initWithKey:@"details.closeDate" ascending:NO];
    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sort]];

    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController =
        [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest
            managedObjectContext:managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil
            cacheName:@"Root"];
    self.fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;
    _fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

    return _fetchedResultsController;

}
```

What I'm finding after using instruments to profile the code is that the `NSFetchedResultsController` is taking about twice as long to load the objects into the `UITableView` as my initial method was. This line in particular:

```
BankInfo *bankInfo = [_fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
```

is taking 292 ms whereas loading the entire array of `BankInfos` is taking about 150 ms. Anyone know why this is?

Comment: Are you sure this isn't a case of premature optimization? How many frames-per-second are you getting when scrolling?

Comment: @MichaelG.Emmons - The frames per second are extremely bad, only in the 20s (mind you this is an iPhone4), it's very choppy as the BankInfos are initially loaded for each cell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem I was having didn't have to do with CoreData performance, but had to do with the fact that I was accidentally saving / loading full size images as thumbnails in the tableview. Once I fixed this, the performance issues went away.

Comment: If you want to improve performance more, it's usually a good idea to have your images in a separate entity. This allows core data to fault the image data until it's needed and refault it as necessary. I typically do this even if I'm only storing thumbnails.

Comment: @MichaelG.Emmons - thanks for reminding me about this, remember Apple also recommended this in the Core Data guide.

Answer (score 1):

Well, we are talking about ms, it is still quite fast.

The fetched results controller is doing a query to sqllite for each cell. You can turn on sqllite debug in xcode: `-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 1` and see for yourself.
The NSArray is populated, stored, and fetched entirely in memory.

The choice between an array and fetched controller is not to be done by taking 'speed' into account.

Basically, if you have a small array of objects, immutable while on screen, then you can safely choose NSArray as table datasource.

Instead, if you have lot of objects or planning to have a growing numbers of objects, that also need to be refreshed often, NSFetchedResultsController is the preferred choice.

Comment: +1 thanks. Problem was actually my fault (see below).